# XCode - How to access Data in specific filepaths

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to access data (xml, to be specific) in different filepaths, depending on some parameters. In short, theres a /Saves/ folder, which contains several other folders (/Save1/, /Save2/, /Save3/, etc). I want to be able to parse.

Lets assume the file I want to access is in the following path:

```
/../projectname/Saves/Save1/dialogue.xml
```

Within *finder* I created the folder substructure and then copied it into my XCode project. That means, these folders exist in the filestructure and not just in XCode.
Afterwards I'm trying to do the following:

```
NSString *path = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:"@/Saves/Save1/dialogue.xml"];
NSData *xmlData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

However, that doesn't seem to work properly. Logging the path variable I get the following:

```
/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Application/<appcode>/<appname>.app/Saves/Save1/dialogue.xml
```

Where's my mistake? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: the file you are loading is not in the bundle. Bundle files are those packaged (zipped) inside the .app file. You can write to your bundle so it's a bit confusing. But normally people write and read from there documents directory. However, in iOS you can't read any file from your computer because the app run in a sandbox that has restricted rights to it's documents directory or bundle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure you have added same folder in project target also. One you add the same structure under project target and compile then same folders will be created in your .app file. then you can access it the way you mentioned.

Comment: Are you refering to checking the "Add to targets" Box while adding the folder to xcode? If so - no difference and I'm quite sure I had that checked in the first place. If you mean I need to add that somewhere else (in the build settings?), I wouldn't know where.

Comment: I mean to say you should add same folder structure inside your project file navigator and make sure to select option "Crearte folder references for any added folders" while adding it to project.

Comment: Yup, we're talking about the same thing then. I did that.

Comment: Ah. No we didn't. After re-reading (dumb me beeing distracted while reading possible solutions) now I understood what you were referring to. It works now - thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
//NSString *path  =  [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"dialogue" ofType:@"xml" inDirectory:@"Saves/Save1"];
NSString *path = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Saves/Save1/dialogue.xml"];
if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExitsAtPath:path])
{
    NSMutableData *xmlData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"File doesnot exits");
}
```

Comment: Works neither with inDirectory:@"Save", nor with inDirectory:@"Save1", nor with inDirectory:@"Save/Save1". Thanks anyways! :)

Comment: inDirectory:@"Saves/Save1" is this

Comment: No difference. Just that, instead of just doing nothing, now I get the log. The same for Saves, Save1 and Saves/Save1.